# Javascript to call controller to populate Textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to enable an edit button to use Javascript, to post a json query to my MVC controller to get data, and then populate a form, client side, with data returned from the json query. And I am failing. And I am not sure I am doing the right way.

I am showing a list of 'Sub Categories' on my view.

```
@foreach (var sub in Model.SubCategories)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">

                    @Html.ActionLink(" ", "DeleteSubCategory", "Category", new { subCategoryId = sub.Id }, new {@class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove", @title="Delete"}) 
                    <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit btnEditSubCategory" onclick="populateSubCategory(@sub.Id);"></a>

                    @sub.Description
                </div>

            </div>

        }
```

The `<a href` is where I am going very wrong. I want that to call my javascript, which is where I am probably going even MORE wrong, which si supposed to take the id from the link above, go to the controller, grab the data I need based on the id, and then populate an editbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function populateSubCategory(id) {
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EditSubCategory", "Category")',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(id),
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success == 'true') {
                document.getElementById("txtSubCategoryName").value = result.Description;
                window.location = '@Url.Action("EditCategory", "Category", new { categoryId = Model.Id })';
               } else {
                   alert(result.Message);
               }
            },
        error: function () {
            alert("Oh no...");
        }

    });
    return (false);
}
```

I believe my javascript is probably wrong as well.

Can someone assist me with fixing this?

What happens at the moment, is that my value in my controller is null:

```
public JsonResult EditSubCategory(string subCategoryId)
{
    var result = new { Success = "true", Description = "Test Description" };
    var r = new JsonResult
    {
        Data = result
    };

    return r;
}
```

Note, my controller does nothing right now. I am just trying to populate the text box. But `subCategoryId` is always null.

Additionally, when I try assign the value, I get:

`JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference`

The form that has the edit boxes I want to populate is this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal well">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtSubCategoryName" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Sub Category Name:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input type="text" class="txtSubCategoryName form-control" placeholder="The description of the Sub Category" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cmbCostCentre" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Default Cost Centre:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <select class="form-control cmbCostCentre">
            <option value="0">None</option>
            @foreach (var cc in Model.AvailableCostCentres)
            {
                <option value="@cc.Value">@cc.Text</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Saying it "fails" is the same as saying it "doesn't work". Explain what you're expecting to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: Sorry - updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the data argument in your ajax call to:

```
{subCategoryId :id}
```

Comment: I now use: data: JSON.stringify({ subCategoryId: id }) - Is that right? The value seems to now get to the controller. Result is right. Method is correct?

Comment: I don't think you need the stringify.  Since you are specifying the content type as JSON -- and giving jquery an object instead of a string -- jquery should take it from there.  I've seen it done both ways.